# Voltage gain of differential amp with active load (OTA)

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, circuit-analysis, differential-amplifier, ota

In solving the differential pair with an active load and parasite resistance R1 is included, I am stuck on how to proceed.

[image]

This was a question from Razavi's Design of analog CMOS integrated circuit, Ch 5, problem 22. For differential gain, if M1, M2 and M3,M4 is symmetrical and gmro>>>>1, I can simplify one input at a time with vd/2 and -vd/2 with AC ground. However, I'm stuck on calculating the output resistance.

[image]

From problem a, the author calculates the output resistance with parallel of 2ron(=ro1+ro2) and rop(=ro4). Bit, since V1(drain of the M1) isn't fixed, I think output resistance is just parallel of ron and rop (same as normal case).

Also, from problem b, I can't understand second equivalent circuit. Why resistance of V1 is parallel of "2ron" and 1/gm3?? Isn't it ron and 1/gm3? Moreover, even in this case, is Rout still the same with problem a?